# Serial port performance - VB.NET vs C++ & Boost

Tags: c++, vb.net, performance, serial-port, boost-asio

I'm having trouble understanding why my application takes so long to communicate with a device over a serial port on Windows 10. I've written two small test applications to try to see what makes it so slow. Here's the code for both of them:

```vb
''VB.NET code    
Imports System.IO.Ports

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim port As New SerialPort("COM3", 921600, Parity.None, 8, 1)

        port.Open()

        port.DtrEnable = True
        port.RtsEnable = True

        Dim profiler As New Stopwatch

        profiler.Start()

        For i As Integer = 1 To 100
            port.Write("1PA?" & vbCrLf)
            port.ReadLine()
            port.Write("TB" & vbCrLf)
            port.ReadLine()
        Next

        profiler.Stop()

        Console.WriteLine("Average: " & profiler.ElapsedMilliseconds / 100 & "ms")

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

And:

```cpp
//C++ code
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "boost/asio/io_service.hpp"
#include "boost/asio/serial_port.hpp"
#include "boost/asio/read_until.hpp"
#include "boost/asio/write.hpp"
#include "boost/asio/streambuf.hpp"
#include "boost/asio/buffer.hpp"
#include "boost/thread.hpp"
#include "boost/ref.hpp"
#include "boost/lexical_cast.hpp"

using boost::asio::io_service;
using boost::asio::serial_port;
using boost::asio::streambuf;

size_t read_until(serial_port& port, streambuf& buf, const std::string& delim)
{
    return boost::asio::read_until(port, buf, delim);
}

void complete(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    if (error)
        std::cout << "Error\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Starting...\n";

    io_service io;
    serial_port port(io, "COM3");
    streambuf buf(1000);

    boost::posix_time::ptime t0 = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();

    port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits(boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits::one));
    port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity());
    port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control(boost::asio::serial_port::flow_control::hardware));
    port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(921600));
    port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::character_size(8));


    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        boost::asio::write(port, boost::asio::buffer("1PA?\r\n", 6));

        read_until(port, buf, "\r\n");
        buf.consume(buf.size());

        boost::asio::write(port, boost::asio::buffer("TB\r\n", 4));

        read_until(port, buf, "\r\n");
        buf.consume(buf.size());
    }

    boost::posix_time::ptime tE = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();

    std::cout << (tE-t0).total_milliseconds() << '\n';

    std::cin.get();
}
```

The problem is that the VB.NET code reports an average of ~6ms per loop iteration (i.e. 3ms per write/read pair), while the C++ code takes over 60ms per iteration.

The rest of the project is written in C++, so I need to improve that code and can't simply use the other one. Currently, the fastest way I found is to communicate over TCP/IP with a VB.NET application that routes TCP/IP to a serial port. Strangely, this is more than twice as fast as the direct C++ implementation despite the additional steps involved.

Is there anything I'm missing, perhaps a setting in the C++ implementation? I've already tried all flow-control options, different buffer sizes, ...

Comment: Are you testing with an optimized build? If not, do so.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: That is very unlikely to make a difference here.

Comment: Did you try profiling it?

Comment: You're using `boost` for I/O which emphasizes portability first of all, and then throughput.  Responsiveness would be much much better using the OS API.

Comment: @Ben Voigt It's still step one in "how to profile".

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes, I tried that - the fully optimized program takes nearly the same amount of time

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, but I only got the sampling profiler working - and that one reports 40 samples with 1000samples/s over 10s, so that information is not worth so much I think (Could it just come from the fact that nearly all time is spent in OS API calls?). I'll try to get instrumentation running once more, maybe that will give a more meaningful result

Comment: @BenVoigt I stepped through the whole boost code - it's just a few trivial wrappers around the WINAPI calls. Also, while I get that it wont be as fast as an implementation that is coded specifically for one OS, I don't see why the speed difference should be a factor of 10 - that seems a bit ridiculous in my opinion

Comment: @Mathe172: The problem isn't the thickness of the wrapper, but the controls that is doesn't expose.  In particular, with the Win32 API you can have a profound impact on the timing with careful use of `SetCommTimeouts`.  Since there's no exact equivalent on other OSes, a portable API can't give the same level of control (total and intercharacter intervals).  It's not 10 times less efficient, it's just 10 times higher latency, and this absolutely can be explained by timeout settings.

Comment: Just to confirm my assumptions, is this "serial port" a USB device, or a true 16x50 on PCI/ISA bus?  The `read_until` can't see into the receive buffer on a USB device, so it has to wait for the scheduled transfer of that buffer to the kernel buffer.  And that scheduled transfer is likely to be what Boost is setting up totally differently (and for your intended purpose, wrong).

Comment: So I recommend getting the Win32 HANDLE using the `native()` member function, and calling `SetCommTimeouts` with a very low intercharacter limit (`ReadIntervalTimeout = 1`).

Comment: @BenVoigt It's indeed a device attached over USB. I will try your suggestion and see if it helps

Comment: FWIW, at 0.9 Mbps, the USB latency is going to be the biggest factor in responsiveness.  If you can pipeline transfers (send both commands in a single write instead of waiting for the first read to complete), you'll probably cut your time in half again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 60 ms you are seeing for a write/read/write/read sequence corresponds pretty well to typical defaults for scheduled transfers.  Here's the port configuration for an FTDI (very popular chipset for USB serial ports)

[image]

If the serial port initialization code doesn't explicitly set timeouts, what you get is the scheduled transfers every 16ms.

If you instead call [`SetCommTimeouts`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363437(v=vs.85).aspx), you can arrange for the USB device to forward the received data buffer every time there's a gap on the serial RX wire.  To do this, set the [`ReadIntervalTimeout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363190(v=vs.85).aspx) to the transfer time for just a couple bytes.  At 921 kbaud, each byte takes 10-11 microseconds, so the lowest possible timeout of 1 millisecond for `ReadIntervalTimeout` corresponds to a gap of about 92 bytes.

However, due to the different quality-of-implementation of drivers that come with various USB devices, it's possible to run into devices that don't have hardware support for inter-character timeout.  In such cases, it is probably best to disable `ReadIntervalTimeout` and `ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier`, and just use `ReadTotalTimeoutConstant`.

Using either of these timeout configurations, the data transfer across USB will occur more timely and your code will make progress.

However, the USB latency will still be on the order of 3 milliseconds per receive (1 while the RX line is busy, 1 ms idle to trigger the timeout, and another 1 ms to wait for the next USB timeslot).  To do better than 1 message every 3 milliseconds, you need to pipeline so that multiple messages are in-flight, by replacing the stop-and-wait protocol with some sliding window scheme.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer and explanation. Looking at the code, it seems that boost already does what you're suggesting (see [here](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/develop/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_serial_port_service.ipp#L101)). However, I got it working by doing what is mentioned in the Remarks section in the [documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363190(v=vs.85).aspx) you linked, i.e. setting `ReadIntervalTimeout` and `ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier` to MAXDWORD and `ReadTotalTimeoutConstant` to `1`.

Comment: @Mathe172: Well, I know that my C++ code doesn't suffer from such long latency. But then, I don't use I/O Completion Ports, I use completion callbacks (`ReadFileEx` for example). On the other hand, although boost's code says 'iocp' here, there, and everywhere, `read_until` calls `do_read` which seems to be using `GetOverlappedResult` not Completion Ports. Perhaps you could capture a trace (including timing) of the I/O operations on the serial port? Sysinternals tools, either Port Monitor or Process Monitor, should be quite good at that.  Then we'll see whether the reads are getting split, etc.

Comment: @Mathe172: I see you edited your comment while I was doing further research.  That combination of timeouts would be an effective workaround for a USB device that doesn't support inter-character timeouts, only total timeouts.  Because then the inter-character timeout would be emulated in software, and only process after the scheduled buffer transfer takes place.  I'll add that possibility to my answer.

Comment: Thanks once again for the explanation!